# limit display image take from database and display the newest image

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to limit display 3 images to a row. Only a row, however, I really don't get it how to limit the number of images to display and how to display newest image to first, it's only display newest to the last row. I am trying some way, but nothing work.

Upload

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $target_dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/store/';
    $target = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $db =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image");
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $title = $_POST['image_title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, title, description) VALUE ('$image', '$title', '$description')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {
        // header("location:../../gallery/gallery.html");
        header("location: ../test.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Display

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$count = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $listImage = $row['image'];
    echo "<img src='store/".$listImage."' width='250' height='250'>";
}
```

Comment: Do you have an auto-increment `id` field or something like `created_at` column in images table?

Comment: You must use a `DATETIME` column in your table and `ORDER BY DESC` using that field to get the newest image.

Comment: Dont forget `LIMIT 1`  or however many you want.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Why does he/she need to add `LIMIT 1`? He/She wants to fetch all the rows and latest on the top followed by others.

Comment: because I am not sure what this means `I am trying to display 3 image to a row. Only a row, however,` and  in the title `limit display image  ....` etc..  This could mean they want only the most recent image, the last 3 images, or 3 images per row.  Or something completely different.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix haha, agree. This question deserves an edit.

Comment: Oh, LIMIT is thing I need, thank. But I still do not know how to display newest image

Comment: Do an `order by id desc LIMIT 1` if you have `id` as an autoincrement field in `images` table. This will display latest image.

Comment: Well first you need a way to know how recent any image is, for that make a DATETIME field, and when an image is created insert the current date into that field. Then you can query and ORDER by that data, then limit to what you want.

Comment: You may be able to use the ID becuase it's sequential. but You will have no real way to know when an image was created.  What if you wanted the most recent images of last month, or you modify an image (update the date) and want it to show as new etc.  A date is more flexible in its utility.  Another example is what if you want only the most recent images today, with an ID you have no way to know that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It depends more on the use case because doing an order by on a primary key won't hurt much. Let this user update the table structure in the question to make it more clear.

Comment: That is a fair point.

Comment: So that mean I have to create a Date time when I upload image to database, right?

Comment: @Buche_De_Noel Please run the queries as mentioned in the answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1:

You may need to update your table with an `auto_increment` column or a `DATETIME` column that should save the current time in the table.

Let's consider adding an `auto_increment` `id` field in `images` table. You need to run this command to do so:

```
ALTER TABLE `images` 
  ADD `id` INT NOT NULL auto_increment first, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

### Step 2:

Change your SQL query to:

```
// to get the latest image stored in the images table.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

It will do the job for you! Also, I have added `LIMIT 1` - you can change it whatever count of latest images you want

> **Note:** If you want to get the most recent images of the last month, or you modify an image (update the date), in such cases, please
>   consider adding a `DATETIME` column in the table and use that in
>   `order by` clause.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks mate!